# What's the right word for someone who shows they can't do something so no one will ever ask them?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for someone who deliberately proves or shows they can't do something, so that no one ever asks them to do it?

Comment: "lazy slacker" is not too far, but it's not a perfect match..